# Resizing a JPanel in BorderLayout Manager

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am developing a GUI. I used BoderLayout manager for my JFrame. I added a JPanel to the North region of the Frame. The problem is the theJPanel is not taking in the size that i have assigned for the height. It is very small. Is there a way of resizing the JPanel?

Here is the whole source code:

```
public class JPanelDemo {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();

JPanelDemo() {
    createFrame();
}

public void createFrame() {
    //create the frame

    frame = new JFrame("GUI Sample");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(750, 300));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2147483647, 2147483647));
    frame.setVisible(true);
//create the panel

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.yellow, Color.black));
    panel.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32767, 32767));
    panel.setSize(new Dimension(732, 146));

    BorderLayout layout= new BorderLayout();
    layout.setHgap(3);
    layout.setVgap(10);

    frame.setLayout(layout);
    frame.add(panel,"North");
    frame.add(new JButton("button"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanelDemo jpd = new JPanelDemo();
}
```

}

Comment: okay fine here is the code for sizing the panel:'panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32767, 32767));
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(732, 146));'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing "North" try

BorderLayout.NORTH

or

BorderLayout.FIRST_LINE

Also instead of the hackish way you are using to make sure the frame can grow indefinitely, I think it will look cleaner if you use `setPreferredSize`

Comment: yaeh i did that but nothing is changing concerning the resizing of the panel

Comment: So when you add the panel, the height is still smaller than it should be?